# How do i replace "\" with "&#92;"

Tags: java, replace, special-characters, str-replace

I tried using

```
string.replace("\","&#92;");
```

But this doesn't work and gives me a compilation error

```
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

Comment: Have you heard of escape characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like bellow, You need [escape Special characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html)

```
string.replace("\\","&#92;");
```

Answer (score 0):

escape the special characters.

```
string.replace("\\","&#92;");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String p = ...;
p.replaceAll("\\\\", "&#92;");
System.out.println(p);
```

use this code to replace and getting output in console..

Thanks..